# Google indexing issue

Tags: seo

I made a wordpress based website for a client. After it was finished I submitted the site on google as I always do with all other sites - put a google webmasters generated .html file in the website root and made a sitemap.xml.

The site was not showing up during the first week, so I resubmitted the sitemap. Same thing again after 2 weeks.

A couple of days ago I noticed that the client was exploring the wordpress administration and accidentally check "block my site from search engines" - which added the `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` in the head tag.

I removed that now, and resubmitted the sitemap. My question is - will I get penalties for resubmitting the sitemap and how long do I have to wait for google bot to index this site?

Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll not get any penalities for resubmitting. Google doesn't worry about how many time you submit a sitemap.

For the wait time, no one can tell you when Google will crawl again your website. It depends on several factors but, as a general rule, you can think that Google crawl more often those websites that update frequently their contents and create frequently new ones.